# Simple Date Format for the Following Values in Android

Tags: android, date, kotlin, simpledateformat

Please provide the Simple Date format for the following in android

The DateFormat of 21/08/2021 -> SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

I Want the SimpleDateFormat for the following two Values

The DateFormat of January 01, 2021 at 3:37:59 PM UTC+5:30 -> SimpleDateFormat("?")

The DateFormat of Wed Sep 15 10:10:59 GMT+05:30 2021 -> SimpleDateFormat("?")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use `java.time`?

Comment: If you know upfront the several possible formats the input can take, then I would recommend bundling them all into a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and using that.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

1. For the first format, you can build the required `DateTimeFormatter` using the  `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.
2. For the second pattern, you can simply use `DateTimeFormatter` with the required pattern letters.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));

        DateTimeFormatter dtf1 = 
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("MMMM dd, uuuu 'at' h:mm:ss a 'UTC'")
                .appendOffset("+H:mm", "Z")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        System.out.println(now.format(dtf1));

        DateTimeFormatter dtf2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss OOOO uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(now.format(dtf2));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
September 15, 2021 at 10:22:43 PM UTC+5:30
Wed Sep 15 22:22:43 GMT+05:30 2021
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wAElzU)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>